# Bind to output string using Oracle.ManagementDataAccess

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

All

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO T1(CODE, NAME) VALUES(:Code, :Name) RETURNING 'Hello' INTO :NewId
```

This code works fine (I checked it in sqldeveloper).

I used Oracle command from Oracle.ManagementDataAccess:

```
cmd.Text = @"INSERT INTO T1(CODE, NAME) VALUES(:Code, :Name) RETURNING 
'Hello' INTO :NewId";
 var codeParameter = new OracleParameter("Code", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
 codeParameter.Value = templateName;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(codeParameter);

 var nameParameter = new OracleParameter("Name", 
    OracleDbType.Varchar2);
 nameParameter.Value = reportProps.Description;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParameter);

 var newIdParameter = new OracleParameter("NewId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
     100, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(newIdParameter);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ExecuteNonQuery() works fine, but I have empty newIdParameter.Value.

If I return integer number instead of 'Hello' and change OracleDbType.Varchar2 with OracleDbType.Int32 I will get right number in newIdParameter.Value.

What I do wrong when I bind to varchar2 output parameter?

Answer (score 0):

For return values you should (or must) set also the `DbType` property and you must read the return value after `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Proper use for integer return values would be like this:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME) VALUES(:Name) RETURNING 123 INTO :NewId", con) ) {
cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "dummy";           
cmd.Parameters.Add("NewId", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters["NewId"].DbType = DbType.Int32;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var ret = cmd.Parameters["NewId"].Value;

Debug.WriteLine("ret = {0}", ret);
```

And for string do it like this:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME) VALUES(:Name) RETURNING 'Hello' INTO :NewId", con) ) {
cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "dummy";           
cmd.Parameters.Add("NewId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters["NewId"].DbType = DbType.String;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var ret = cmd.Parameters["NewId"].Value;

Debug.WriteLine("ret = {0}", ret);
```